# Drupal hates webforms, the submit button is gone. Help?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, forms

**Problem Photo**: http://screensnapr.com/v/n4MiiA.png

**Problem**: 
When I add a **form component** with drupal 6 webforms to a page is **doesn't add it** to the list of components (that should exists). The **submit button is gone/missing**.

I have a good many modules installed and I'm looking around hoping none of them removed or added any kind of **jQuery objects**.

Has anyone had this happen or know what might be the influencing characteristic? is the problem jQuery?

**List of modules**: http://screensnapr.com/v/icivOF.png

**Page Head**: http://screensnapr.com/v/5nSEEX.png

**Form**: http://screensnapr.com/v/wqDGGE.png

**Drupal Version**: 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**:

I went in and did the following to get webforms working:

- uninstalled modules: chaos tools, context, webforms
- reinstall the above and updated webforms
- added a component "email as email as mandatory"

Comment: corrupt DB is what I assume based on my results.